# Implementation of Mutual Information

Tags: java, information-retrieval

I have a collection of text documents in a Lucene index. There are a bit over 4.000.000 documents in the index. The program runs a search based on a user query and returns N documents relevant to the query. The idea then is to perform a mutual information calculation on terms in the N documents and find terms that strongly relate to the collection as a whole.

Basically, given the query "computer", the program should return a list of terms like "computer, network, programmer, client, server" and so on. This should work in theory, but I never get the expected result and I cannot tell if I'm just implementing it wrong, or if there is something about my collections that makes this inefficient..

This is the code:

```
public class CoOccurrence {
    private Map<String, Double> cooccurrenceMatrix = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    private int n;
    private List<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();

    public CoOccurrence(List<String> abstracts){
        n = abstracts.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < abstracts.size(); i++){
            String[] line = abstracts.get(i).split(" ");
            for(String word: line){
                if(!Utils.containsDigits(word)){
                    if(!terms.contains(word)){
                        terms.add(word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        getMutualInformation(abstracts);
    }

    private void getMutualInformation(List<String> abstracts){
        double n = this.n;
        double sum;

        for(int f1 = 0; f1 < terms.size()-1; f1++){
            sum = 0;
            for(int f2 = f1 + 1; f2 < terms.size(); f2++){
                Bigram bigram = new Bigram(terms.get(f1), terms.get(f2));

                //Fetch number of documents that contains both term.f1 and term.f2
                double p_xy = docsContainingXandY(bigram, abstracts) / n;

                //Fetch number of documents containing term.f1
                double p_x = docsContainingX(bigram, abstracts) / n;

                //Fetch number of documents containing term.f2
                double p_y = docsContainingY(bigram, abstracts) / n;

                sum += (p_xy) * Utils.logWithoutNaN( p_xy / (p_x * p_y) );
            }
            cooccurrenceMatrix.put(terms.get(f1), sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see that I'm performing the calculations in some erroneous way or any other mistakes or misunderstandings that hinders the desired outcome?

EDIT: The Bigram class is a simple wrapper that contains two Strings: String x, String y.

The Util class contains a lot of different tasks, but the logWithoutNaN looks like this:

```
public static double logWithoutNaN(double value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        return Math.log(EPSILON);
    } else if (value < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Math.log(value);
}
```

Where EPSILON = 0.000001

As for the output: A search for "computer" gives 20 terms that are supposed to be relevant, but just are (mostly) not: "processing called south east asia regional confederation rim searcc association not-for-profit input national general meaning professional provide associations science give"

Comment: Need to know more, especially since we don't have the `BigGram` and `Utils` classes. What's the error or bad output? Please provide more information, like a stack trace.

Comment: @aliteralmind I have added the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come immediately to mind. But, it's hard to speak to as I don't know your data (how many docs, how big, etc.)

But right of the bat, `terms` should be a Set, not a list, then the "contains" (which is scanning the list continually) should be more efficient.

Next, while the separation is a laudable goal, I'd combine the `docContaining...` routines in to a single routine. You iterating through the list of docs, and I assume their entire content, 3 times. You (likely) could be scanning them once and deriving all 3 values (`p_xy`, `p_x`, `p_y`) simultaneously.

So, simply I just see a lot of repetitive scanning where perhaps a some better choice of algorithms and data structure could potentially have a large impact.

Addenda: Amazing what a shower can bring.

The fundamental issue here, is the main double `for` loop in the center where you are iterating across the word pairs. This is what is killing you. It's n^2. More words, far worse performance.

So the real goal is to eliminate words early.

First, you should run a stemmer on the words. Stemming eliminate things like plurals and contractions and what not. You should also eliminate common stop words ("the", "a", "then", etc.). Both of these processes will reduce the word count. You can search around for stemming algorithms, Lucene certainly has these already.

Next, I'd create unique word lists for each document. From these lists, I would start eliminating words unique to the documents. Obviously if a word only exists in a single document, there is no correlation whatsoever across the document set.

Finally, I'd start throwing out little used words that are shared. If you're interested in EVERY correlation, then you don't want to do this. But most folks are interested in the "top few". So, it should be straightforward to eliminate early those words that clearly will not rise up to the top of the list. Words that are used only once in 2 documents, for example. You might try some heuristic, like averaging the word occurrences across all of the documents, and dropping those words below a particular threshold.

The goal of all of these is to reduce the overall word list, since each new word offers such dramatic impact on overall performance.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that it is not what you might call time efficient right now. However, none of these things alter the outcome of the program, which is what I'm stuck at right now. I will edit my entry with some more info.

Comment: You raise some excellent ideas to get better performance here, but first of all: while stemming may reduce the total word count, it is destructive for search precision, which is what I'm aiming for here. (Stemming is good for recall, and bad for precision). Secondly: this does not really answer my question at all. My problem is not performance. Yes it is a slow, non-optimal program, but I'm not bothered with performance right now. First I need this to give the expected output.